# How do i default select radio button

Tags: angularjs

I have `Gender` radio options for repeating students. See my code below.
How do i select default radio as `'Male'` for each student?

```
<ng-repeat student in Students>
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-sm-8">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gender </label>
    <div class="button-holder col-lg-2">
        <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" id="radioY_{{$index + $parent.$index}}" data-ng-model="student.Gender" data-ng-value="true" />
        <label for="radioY_{{$index + $parent.$index}}">
            <span class="Radiobox-txt" id="radioY_{{$index}}">Male</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder col-lg-2">
        <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" id="radioN_{{$index + $parent.$index}}" data-ng-model="student.Gender"  data-ng-value="false" />
        <label for="radioN_{{$index + $parent.$index}}">
            <span class="Radiobox-txt" id="radioN_{{$index + $parent.$index}}">Female</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, ```ng-value="true"``` should do this job, what is actually happening? P.S. You have a typo in your HTML, where the second radio button is supposed to be - ```<inputtype```

Comment: It does not work. When my page loads Male is not default selected. Do i need to inject anything in my controller? Type is my mistake in posted question, in code it is fine. no typo

Comment: value and checked are not the same thing

Comment: @ charlietfl, good point, i want to default select one of the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-value` should contain the value you want to set to your model after the radio button is selected.
In your case assign `ng-value` with 'Male' and while defining object `student` assign 'Male' to `student.Gender`

Comment: I was missing this point "while defining object student assign 'Male' to student.Gender".. thanks